# Get all fields from an interface

Tags: go, reflection, struct, reply

How do I know the fields I can access from the `reply` object/interface? I tried reflection but it seems you have to know the field name first. What if I need to know all the fields available to me?

```
// Do sends a command to the server and returns the received reply.
Do(commandName string, args ...interface{}) (reply interface{}, err error)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) function to obtain a [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) type descriptor. From there, you can list fields of the dynamic value stored in the interface.

Example:

```
type Point struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

var reply interface{} = Point{1, 2}
t := reflect.TypeOf(reply)
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t.Field(i))
}
```

Output:

```
{Name:X PkgPath: Type:int Tag: Offset:0 Index:[0] Anonymous:false}
{Name:Y PkgPath: Type:int Tag: Offset:4 Index:[1] Anonymous:false}
```

The result of a `Type.Field()` call is a [`reflect.StructField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField) value which is a `struct`, containing the name of the field among other things:

```
type StructField struct {
    // Name is the field name.
    Name string
    // ...
}
```

If you also want the values of the fields, you may use [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) to obtain a [`reflect.Value()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), and then you may use [`Value.Field()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field) or [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName):

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(reply)
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    fmt.Println(v.Field(i))
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/a8hfdu-p4-).

Note: often a pointer to struct is wrapped in an interface. In such cases you may use `Type.Elem()` and [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) to "navigate" to the pointed type or value:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(reply).Elem()

v := reflect.ValueOf(reply).Elem()
```

If you don't know whether it's a pointer or not, you can check it with `Type.Kind()` and [`Value.Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Kind), comparing the result with `reflect.Ptr`:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(reply)
if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    t = t.Elem()
}

// ...

v := reflect.ValueOf(reply)
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TnHP6N0oyH).

For a detailed introduction to Go's reflection, read the blog post: [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).